# Choosing an array size based on a template argument in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

Consider this code:

```
enum class EnumType
{
  Type1,
  Type2
};

constexpr std::size_t the_length;

template <EnumType T>
int function()
{
  std::array<uint8_t, the_length> x;
  //some code here that uses x 
}
```

I would like the length of array `x` to have a different value based on the type `T`. For example if `T` can take one of 2 values (`Type1`, `Type2`), I would like `the_length` to have value 10 if `T==Type1`, and a value of 20 if `T==Type2`. Can this be done in C++11? Thanks

Comment: What does "if `T` can take two values" mean?

Comment: did you mean `template<typename T>` ?

Comment: It might be helpful to include an example of how you imagine the call site would look

Comment: It looks like `T` is sometimes used as an enumerated type of type `EnumType` (in the argument list) and sometimes as a typename (in the parameter list for `std::array`). Can you clarify?

Comment: edited the question to make it clearer. T can be equal to Type1 or Type2

Comment: @astrophobia you cannot use `T` as first template argument to `std::array`. `T` is an enumerator, but that argument must be a type name

Comment: edited the code again to clarify better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What wrong with the good old ternary operator?

```
template <EnumType T>
int function()
{
  std::array<SomeType, T == EnumType::Type1 ? 10u : 20u> x;
}
```

If `T` is a `typename`, and not a value of some type, you have only to change the test

```
template <typename T>
int function()
{
  std::array<T, std::is_same<SomeType1, T>::value ? 10u : 20u> x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @templatetypedef said, but C++11 can do even more than that:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

enum class EnumType { T1, T2 };

template<EnumType T>
struct my_array_traits;

template<>
struct my_array_traits<EnumType::T1> {
    using type = float;
    constexpr static std::size_t value = 5;
};

template<>
struct my_array_traits<EnumType::T2> {
    using type = double;
    constexpr static std::size_t value = 10;
};

template<EnumType T>
struct my_other_array_traits;

template<>
struct my_other_array_traits<EnumType::T1> {
    using type = short;
    constexpr static std::size_t value = 20;
};

template<>
struct my_other_array_traits<EnumType::T2> {
    using type = long;
    constexpr static std::size_t value = 40;
};


template <EnumType T, template<EnumType> class array_traits>
int function()
{
    std::array<typename array_traits<T>::type,
               array_traits<T>::value> x;
    //some code here that uses x 
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    function<EnumType::T1, my_array_traits>();
    function<EnumType::T2, my_array_traits>();
    function<EnumType::T1, my_other_array_traits>();
    function<EnumType::T2, my_other_array_traits>();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is possible. You just need another level of indirection. Here's one way to do this:

```
/* array_for<T>::type gives you your array type. */
template <EnumType T> struct array_for;

/* Specialize to give different values based on what T is. */
template <> struct array_for<Option1> {
    using type = std::array<WhateverTypeYouWantToUse1, 10>;
};
template <> struct array_for<Option2> {
    using type = std::array<WhateverTypeYouWantToUse2, 20>;
};

template <EnumType T>
int function()
{
  typename array_for<T>::type myArray;
  /* do whatever coding dance with myArray seems most fitting. */
}
```

Here, the `array_for` helper `struct` template takes as input an `EnumType` and then outputs a different type of array based on what it finds.

Comment: You can specalize a variable template (since C++14), no need for a wrapper struct

Comment: @M.M I believe the OP's question is specifically in reference to C++11.